# How do I find if all the S3 objects are restored

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently have restored S3 Deep Archive objects using Python.

There are over a million of them and I need to make it sure clearly.

If possible, I would like to use python to check if all objects have been restored.

Can someone please advice me how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From [`restore_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.restore_object) documentation:

> To get the status of object restoration, you can send a `HEAD` request. Operations return the `x-amz-restore` header, which provides information about the restoration status, in the response.

And under [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object):

> If an archive copy is already restored, the header value indicates when Amazon S3 is scheduled to delete the object copy. For example:
>
> `x-amz-restore: ongoing-request="false", expiry-date="Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"`

Answer (score 0):

Although not Python, here is the logic to perform this use case using ***AWS SDK for Java v2***.

```
package com.example.s3;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;

public class GetObjectRestoreStatus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <bucketName> <keyName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
            "    keyName - A key name that represents the object. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        checkStatus(s3,bucketName,keyName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.getrestorestatus.main]
    public static void checkStatus(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName) {
        try {
            HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(keyName)
                .build();

            HeadObjectResponse response =  s3.headObject(headObjectRequest);
            System.out.println("The Amazon S3 object restoration status is "+response.restore());

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.getrestorestatus.main]
}
```